# How to set a texture with delay

Tags: webgl, three.js

I've tried to set a texture. but it dosent work. How should i set the texture in this case?

here is the code
http://jsfiddle.net/9VgTt/

any hints would be appreciated
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because buffers need to be pre-allocated, you need to render your more complicated material first.

To do that, you can do something like this:

```
window.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry( 10, 20, 30 ),
  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/img/logo.png')})
);
scene.add( mesh );
 
// render once
renderer.render( scene, camera );

// remove map
window.mesh.material.map = null;
window.mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

If you think this is too much of a hack, another solution is to just have a dummy transparent or solid-colored map texture to begin with.

You can read more about this issue at the three.js wiki: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9VgTt/14/

Comment: Thank you for your advice and the hack code.

now my new demo is working because of you.